# Update Dashboard tabs to compare subcontractor to peers then email performance summary

Tags: vba, excel

My macro is cobbled together using some code from Ron DeBruin and various other sources and it currently works but I am sure it is not as efficient or bulletproof as possible. Currently it updates the Weekly or Monthly Dashboard tabs and saves them as a PDF then emails them to the correct subcontractor as well as their manager. Any thoughts on how to make it more efficient or reduce potential errors?

```
Sub BulkSendReports()
    Dim FileName As String
    Dim TitleName As String
    Dim FileLocation As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim Email As String
    Dim SDLEmail As String
    Dim Name As String
    Dim pf1 As PivotField
    Dim pf2 As PivotField
    Dim pf3 As PivotField
    Dim pf4 As PivotField
    Dim IIF_Band As String
    Dim Email_Subject As String
    Email_Subject = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Report Controls").Range("C5").Value
    Dim Email_Body As String
    Email_Body = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Report Controls").Range("C7").Value
    Dim Agent_Count As Integer
    Agent_Count = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Background Data").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row - 1

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

For i = 1 To Agent_Count
Application.StatusBar = "Generating Dashboard for..." & Name

Worksheets("Dashboard").Activate

ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Dashboard").Range("B6").Value = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Background Data").Range("C1").Offset(i, 0)
Set pf1 = ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable3").PivotFields("IIF Band")
Set pf2 = ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable5").PivotFields("IIF Band")
Set pf3 = ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable6").PivotFields("IIF Band")
Set pf4 = ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable7").PivotFields("IIF Band")
IIF_Band = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Calculations").Range("D13").Value
pf1.ClearAllFilters
pf1.CurrentPage = IIF_Band
pf2.ClearAllFilters
pf2.CurrentPage = IIF_Band
pf3.ClearAllFilters
pf3.CurrentPage = IIF_Band
pf4.ClearAllFilters
pf4.CurrentPage = IIF_Band


TitleName = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Calculations").Range("D11").Value
FileLocation = "C:\Users\ARP021\Documents\RSuite\" & TitleName & ".pdf"
Email = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Background Data").Range("B1").Offset(i, 0)
SDLEmail = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Background Data").Range("H1").Offset(i, 0)
Name = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Background Data").Range("A1").Offset(i, 0)

If ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.Count > 1 Then
    MsgBox "There is more then one sheet selected," & vbNewLine & _
           "be aware that every selected sheet will be published"
End If



FileName = RDB_Create_PDF(Source:=ActiveSheet, _
                          FixedFilePathName:=FileLocation, _
                          OverwriteIfFileExist:=True, _
                          OpenPDFAfterPublish:=False)




If FileName <> "" Then
    RDB_Mail_PDF_Outlook FileNamePDF:=FileName, _
                         StrTo:=Email, _
                         StrCC:="", _
                         StrBCC:=SDLEmail, _
                         StrSubject:=Email_Subject, _
                         Signature:=True, _
                         Send:=False, _
                         StrBody:="Hello " & Name & ",<br><br>" & Email_Body
Else
    MsgBox "Not possible to create the PDF, possible reasons:" & vbNewLine & _
           "Microsoft Add-in is not installed" & vbNewLine & _
           "You Canceled the GetSaveAsFilename dialog" & vbNewLine & _
           "The path to Save the file in arg 2 is not correct" & vbNewLine & _
           "You didn't want to overwrite the existing PDF if it exist"
End If



Next i

ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Report Controls").Range("C7").Value = "Enter Email body text here (exluding greetings)."
Application.StatusBar = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

 End Sub



Function RDB_Create_PDF(Source As Object, FixedFilePathName As String, _
                    OverwriteIfFileExist As Boolean, OpenPDFAfterPublish As Boolean) As String
   Dim FileFormatstr As String
   Dim Fname As Variant

    If FixedFilePathName = "" Then

        FileFormatstr = "PDF Files (*.pdf), *.pdf"
        Fname = Application.GetSaveAsFilename("", filefilter:=FileFormatstr, _
                                              Title:="Create PDF")


        If Fname = False Then Exit Function
    Else
        Fname = FixedFilePathName
    End If


    If OverwriteIfFileExist = False Then
        If Dir(Fname) <> "" Then Exit Function
    End If


    On Error Resume Next
    Source.ExportAsFixedFormat _
            Type:=xlTypePDF, _
            FileName:=Fname, _
            Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
            IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
            IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
            OpenAfterPublish:=OpenPDFAfterPublish
    On Error GoTo 0


    If Dir(Fname) <> "" Then RDB_Create_PDF = Fname
 End Function

  Function RDB_Mail_PDF_Outlook(FileNamePDF As String, StrTo As String, _
                          StrCC As String, StrBCC As String, StrSubject As String, _
                          Signature As Boolean, Send As Boolean, StrBody As String)
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

   On Error Resume Next
    With OutMail
    If Signature = True Then .Display
    .To = StrTo
    .CC = StrCC
    .BCC = StrBCC
    .Subject = StrSubject
    .HTMLBody = StrBody & "<br>" & .HTMLBody
    .Attachments.Add FileNamePDF
    If Send = True Then
        .Display
    Else
        .Display
    End If
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0

    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
End Function
```